# How do I get the background color of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

How do I get the background color of a TextView?

When I press the TextView, I want to change the background color according to the background color that is in use.

TextView does not have a method such as:

```
getBackgroundResource()
```

Edit:
I would prefer to get the resId of the background color.

Comment: Or I'm searching a little through the internet but it seems there no way to get such id from a xml defined color. Probably you should change your app and manage background colors programmatically, perhaps keeping trace of color changes during onClick events.

Comment: The color used by a given view might not have a resource ID. The res ID of the background is `R.attr.background`, which corresponds to `<item name="android:background">` in your theme or style. You can [get the color value from the theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468034/712526), and compare that with the TextView's color to see whether it matches.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to get color code of the background try this:

```
if (textView.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) textView.getBackground();
    int colorCode = cd.getColor();
}
```

Comment: i edit my question: how i get from this the resId of the color?

Comment: i tried this, but after the first line in your answer i get cd is null

Comment: How do you set background of your TextView? To use this code it has to be Color, not Gradient or other kind of Drawable

Comment: it was because i didnt set background in the first appearance. i fixed thet, but now cd.getColor() returns me -1

Comment: ok, its very strange. if i first set the background to color.black the getColor() returns me other number (not -1) but it still not the same resID color.black . my "if" is to check if the beckround is equals to white backround, so i replace "if (cd.getColor() == color.white)" to "if (cd.getColor() == -1)" . and it works!

Comment: This numbers are `constant Color IDs` of the some pre-defined colors. You can see the list here : (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

The reason it returns -1 is that, White has -1 constant value. You will see in the list.

Comment: Be careful: this can throw an `Exception`: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable`

Comment: True. RippleDrawable wasn't introduced at the time I answered this question. You would have to check instance of background object before casting. The answer assumes you are using `ColorDrawable`.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin:

```
    val cd = view.background as ColorDrawable
    val colorCode = cd.color
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AppCompat` use this:

```
ViewCompat.getBackgroundTintList(textView).getDefaultColor();
```

---

*Side note*: be careful if you cast to `ColorDrawable`, because it can throw a `ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable`.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

we cant use the consts like color.red or color.white .

we need to figure it up how the

```
int intID = (ColorDrawable) holder.tvChoose.getBackground().getColor();
```

represent it and we have the fake ID of the color

Answer (score 0):

`ColorDrawable.getColor()` will only work with API level above 11, so you can use this code to support it from start.
I am using reflection below API level 11.

```
 public static int getBackgroundColor(TextView textView) {
        Drawable drawable = textView.getBackground();
        if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) drawable;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                return colorDrawable.getColor();
            }
            try {
                Field field = colorDrawable.getClass().getDeclaredField("mState");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object object = field.get(colorDrawable);
                field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mUseColor");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return field.getInt(object);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```