# How to get android:TextView foreground and background color

Tags: android, textview, background-color

I have 6 TextViews in which I declared clickable. all TextViews access the same onClick method.

How can I get the foreground and background colors of the clicked TextView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight forward without caring about anything.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       if (v instanceof TextView)
        int colorOfSelectedTextView = ((TextView) v).getCurrentTextColor();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Murat. How do I get the background color ??

Comment: @S.L. For example like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224152/how-do-i-get-the-background-color-of-a-textview