# How to save textview default background color to apply it later?

Tags: android, android-studio

I simply need to change(toggle) the background colour of a `textview` upon each touch.

So when a user first touches the textview, it turns blue. Upon the next touch it turns back to the **default** **theme color** for the textview. I have not specified any colours at all in any of the XML files so far.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
        android:onClick="ToggleListItemSelectedState"/>
```

In the click handler for the textbox:

```
TextView selectedTextView = (TextView)view;
defaultBackground=//?How to save the default background
```

From this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224152/how-do-i-get-the-background-color-of-a-textview) answer, I tried
  defaultBackground=selectedTextView.getBackground();
  int colorCode = defaultBackground.getColor();

but the `getColor()` isn't recognized.

I need to

- Either get the default textview background colour from the theme

  OR
- Save the background colour the first time the textview is touched and
  then subsequently reset the background using the saved colour.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  mBackgroundColor = ((ColorDrawable) view.getBackground()).getColor();

  view.setBackgroundColor(mBackgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current background of the view using `View#getBackground()`. If you don't set any background, it returns `null`.

The background of the view can be set by `View#setBackground(Drawable)` or `ViewCompat#setBackground(View, Drawable)` if you target APIs below 16.

Therefore probably you want to store the original background and the desired background:

```
mOriginalBackground = textView.getBackground();
mOtherBackground = new ColorDrawable(otherColor);
```

And now toggle between them:

```
if (showOriginalBackground) {
    ViewCompat.setBackground(textView, mOriginalBackground);
} else {
    ViewCompat.setBackground(textView, mOtherBackground);
}

showOriginalBackground = !showOriginalBackground;
```

One of the answers to this question suggested using `View#setBackgroundColor(int)`. Please note, that this will (on API 15 and above) mutate the original background if it is already a `ColorDrawable`. Therefore:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red" />

mOriginalBackground = textView.getBackground(); // red
textView.setBackgroundColor(blue); // mOriginalBackground is now blue!
ViewCompat.setBackground(textView, mOriginalBackground); // user still sees blue!
```

Comment: ViewCompat.setBackground didn't quite work, I still was seeing the changed color. However, your answer did lead me to just setting the background to null ,i.e. selectedTextView.setBackground(null); and that worked. thank you